# Im trying to add a pushpin to an Azure map using SymbolLayer. But on zooming in and out my pushpins are moving instead of the map. How can I fix this?

Tags: bing-maps, azure-maps

I'm trying to migrate my app from Bing maps to Azure maps.
I'm adding a few custom pushpins on my map using the SymbolLayer.
When I try to zoom in or out though, my pushpins are getting displaced while my map stays static. What might be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the issue is that your anchor point of your icon does not align with the point on the icon image you want. You can adjust this in a couple of ways.

- Use the icon options `anchor` setting. Good for most standard icon images.
- Use the icon options `offset` setting. Good for fine tuning.

For example, if the point on your image that you want to "anchor" to the coordinates on the map is the bottom left corner of the image, you could do the following:

```
var layer = new atlas.layer.SymbolLayer(datasource, null, {
    iconOptions: {
        anchor: 'bottom-left'
    }
});
```

Here is a sample to experiment with: https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/?sample=Symbol%20Layer%20Options

Here are the docs on the icon options for a symbol layer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-maps-control/atlas.iconoptions?view=azure-maps-typescript-latest

Comment: I'm using the anchor as well as offset options and they are working fine on the first load as well. But the issue is arising when some data changes. I'm using map.clear() to remove my icons and popups and re-plotting them in that case. Even then the icons appear fine. But zooming in and out disorients the map

Comment: Using map.clear() is a bit excessive, it removes all layers (and their settings) and data sources from the map. If you are simply updating the data, update the data in the data source and everything will flow through. datasource.setShapes will overwrite all data in the data source.

Comment: I'm using a loop to add one data source for each symbol layer and hence my data source object is getting lost outside of it. I think I may need a better approach. But can I call setShapes on sources for the map object?

Comment: The `setShapes` function exists on the DataSource class, so you will need the have a reference to that instance. All layers can get their underlying source using the `getSource` function on the layer. The more data sources you have, the slower your app will become. Usually ten or more data sources is extreme. You can have hundreds of layers before they cause any performance issues. With this in mind, best to use a single data source in most cases, and use expressions and filters with layer styles to change how each item looks. In many cases you could likely use a single layer with expressions

Comment: Here is an example of a symbol layer that uses different icons for points based on a property in the individual point data: https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/?sample=Data-driven%20symbol%20icons

Here are a bunch of examples of data driven styles: https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/?search=data%20driven

Here is the docs on style expressions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/data-driven-style-expressions-web-sdk